# How to hide multiple recipient email addresses firebase extension trigger email

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I use the Firebase Trigger Email extension to send emails. This extension allows to send one email to multiple addresses. When I do this, everything goes well, but the recipient can see all the addresses that are also receiving the email. How do I hide it?

Comment: Could you show the code with which you trigger the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](http://smtps://apikey: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@smtp.sendgrid.net:465) in the Extension's detailed doc, you can use the `bcc` field instead of the `to` one.

To do so, the document you create in the "Email documents collection" (as named in the configuration screen), shall have a `bcc` field instead of a `to` one, as follows:

```
bcc: ['someone1@example.com', 'someone2@example.com', 'someone3@example.com'],
message: {
  subject: 'Hello from Firebase!',
  text: 'This is the plaintext section of the email body.',
  html: 'This is the <code>HTML</code> section of the email body.',
}
```

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what he's trying to achieve

Comment: @JayCodist Well, from the following sentence in the question ("the recipient can see all the addresses that are also receiving the email. How do I hide it?") I understand that the OP wants that the recipients don't see the addresses of the other recipients. Using bcc is the solution in this case, IMHO.

Comment: OK, I get it now. Sorry